# C# Linq SortedList Filtering into SortedList

Tags: c#, linq, filter, sortedlist

I have got some code in which I am doing some weirdness to get information out of a SortedList and back into another SortedList. I do my where clause, then have to individually put all the KeyValuePairs back into a new SortedList.

This *can't* be the most efficient, or indeed the recommended, way of doing this, but I can't seem to find a better way.

Here is the code:

```
SortedList<DateTime, CalendarDay> most_days = 
                                new SortedList<DateTime, CalendarDay>();
List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, CalendarDay>> days = this.all_days.Where (
                                  n => n.Value.IsRequested || n.Value.IsApproved
                                  ).ToList();
foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, CalendarDay> kvp in days)
    most_days.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Any ideas on how I can clean this up (less is more, as they say)?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you could certainly remove the `ToList` call - that's not helping you at all.

You could make the calling code simpler like this:

```
var dictionary = allDays.Where(n => n.Value.IsRequested || n.Value.IsApproved)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
var mostDays = new SortedList<DateTime, CalendarDay>(dictionary);
```

... but that's going to build an intermediate `Dictionary<,>`, so it's hardly efficient.

Another option is that you could write your own `ToSortedList` extension method, e.g.

```
public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TSource, TKey, TValue>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
     Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    var ret = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        ret.Add(keySelector(element), valueSelector(element));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then the calling code will just be:

```
var mostDays = allDays.Where(n => n.Value.IsRequested || n.Value.IsApproved)
                      .ToSortedList(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

I suspect this should be reasonably efficient, as it will always be adding values to the *end* of the list during construction.

(For a complete job you'd want to add overloads accepting custom key comparers etc... see `ToDictionary`.)

Comment: This is why I love this site. Speedy answers which work well and which leave me feeling like I've learned something important. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question (sorry!) - more a question on the question:

- Do you actually need the output to be a `SortedList`?
- Or can you survive with the output being an `IEnumerable` where the results happen to be in the right order?

If you never intend to add/insert more items to `mostDays` collection after you've created it, then you could obviously just create an `IEnumerable` using `var mostDays = allDays.Where(n => n.Value.IsRequested || n.Value.IsApproved);`